# Comparing two strings of the same length char-by-char

Tags: string, r, compare, character, match

I want to compare two strings of the same length and count the number of matches. 
For instance:

```
foo <- "Hello"
bar <- "H3llO"
```

What I need is 3 (matches for "H.ll.")

While this can be performed using `sum(unlist(strsplit(foo,""))==unlist(strsplit(bar,"")))`, I am looking for a particular function or more convenient way for that purpose, is there any?

Comment: Is `strsplit` not fast? Perhaps there is another part of your current approach that is not fast....

Comment: Agree with Ananda. Just looked at code which is a `.Internal` function indicating htat it has already been optimized in C and testing with long strings makes me think it's fairly fast.

Comment: @AnandaMahto Actually I am also looking if there is a particular function for this

Comment: Why not just write your own function?

Comment: @AnandaMahto I have done, but I wanted to develop my R information, I guessed maybe I am missing some standard function for this purpose

Comment: Alternatively, try functions to check string similarty: soundex, jarowinkler, levenshteinSim, etc.? [RecordLinkage](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RecordLinkage/RecordLinkage.pdf)